# Need help with a question regarding the Big Oh

Tags: asymptotics, proof-explanation

In class we are currently covering upper/lower bounds, big Oh and omega and the like. I am pretty good on the "typical" functions one would do, but at a complete loss at "general" statements. This ons function, for example:

$$\forall f\in\mathcal{F}: \lfloor \sqrt{\lfloor f(n)\rfloor }\rfloor \in O(\sqrt{f(n)}).$$

the domain F by the same is all natural numbers that return a real positive number when inputted. My first instinct with something like this is to remove the floors, the general strategy I though to solve this is remove the outer floor, then get rid of the square root, and then the inner floor. But I have no idea how to go about this or if this is even the right way to do it.

Help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the squares?  I suspect they are some character that is not rendering properly.  Please use MathJax-you can find a tutorial in the faq

Comment: i used the to the power of 1/2 to represent squares because i realized the square signs weren't rendering properly, so yeah its all there.

Comment: No, it is not all there. It is only all there for people whose browsers are set up to show the special characters you used. For the rest of us, it is illegible. This is why you should use Mathjax to post.

Comment: Right! Sorry, I have updated the OP. Visible now?

Comment: You can remove the floors by $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, but why do you want to remove the square root?